Does the pullback always exist in an abelian category?
I have the following definition of pullback: given any two morphisms $f \colon A \rightarrow C$, $g \colon B \rightarrow C$, we say that the triple $(P, p_1, p_2)$ is a pullback of $f$ and $g$ if $f \circ p_1 = g \circ p_2$ and if given $(Q, q_1, q_2)$ any other triple satisfying this definition, there is a map $r \colon Q \rightarrow P$ with $p_1 \circ u = q_1$, $p_2 \circ u = q_2$.
My question is if it's true that in any abelian category, the pullback always exists.

You probably want to require there is a unique map $r : Q \to P$ such that ...

Here is the answer as a sequence of exercises.

Show that in a category $C$ with finite products and equalizers, finite limits exist and can be computed using finite products and equalizers. (The dual statement about finite coproducts, coequalizers, and finite colimits follows.)

Show that in an additive category $C$, equalizers exist iff kernels exist, and equalizers can be computed using kernels. Deduce that if $C$ has kernels then it has finite limits, and that these can be computed using finite biproducts and kernels. (Again the dual statement about coequalizers, cokernels, and finite colimits follows.)

Conclude that abelian categories have all finite limits and colimits, and that these can be computed using finite biproducts, kernels, and cokernels.


